# Appending a button onto an element and changing its attributes

Tags: javascript, dom, button, event-handling

Hey guys I'm making a little email app as a personal project for me and I had an issue when I'm appending a button element onto a div using Javascript.

Apparently, the button is displaying but it's almost invisible.

So I tried to change the value of it to "Archive" but it's remaining just a small sliver of a button that I can barely see.

How can I change the value of the button with javascript?

Thanks!  Below is my code:

```
fetch('/emails/' + id)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    
    document.getElementById("message-view").innerHTML = "From: " + email.sender + "<p>To: " + email.recipients + "</p>" + "<p>Sent at: " + email.timestamp + "<p>Subject: " + email.subject + "</p>" + "<p>" + email.body + "</p>";
    const archiveButton = element.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
    archiveButton.value = "Archive";
  });
```

Comment: Check your CSS for `button`.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute doesn't set the button content. Use the `textContent` attribute instead : `archiveButton.textContent = "Archive"`

Answer (score 1):

The value attribute works with input tags

Example :

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

In that case it would work
 **but if you had :**

```
<button> Click Me </button>
```

It would not work.

**You would have to use textContent or innerText**

Example :

```
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.textContent = "Archive"
```